# Why does the 'weighted' f1-score result in a score not between precision and recall?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall, multi-class, f1

On the [F1 score sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) there's a section that explains each of the options for the average parameter. Under the weighted option, it says: "it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall."

I would like to know why this happens. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It appears this can happen already with the `macro` average option.  The statement needs some clarification, but I assume the precision and recall that are supposed to not bound the averaged F1 are themselves the same type of average.

Here's a simple example: $TP=TN=4$, $FP=1$, $FN=16$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{precision}(1)&=\frac{TP}{TP+FP}=0.8, \\
\operatorname{recall}(1)&=\frac{TP}{TP+FN}=0.2, \\
\operatorname{precision}(0)&=\frac{TN}{TN+FN}=0.2, \\
\operatorname{recall}(0)&=\frac{TN}{TN+FP}=0.8
\end{align*}$$

and so $F_1(1)=F_1(0)=0.32$, so the macro-average $F_1$ is also $0.32$.  But the macro-averaged precision and recall are both $0.5$.

Comment: This is indeed a very sensible observation, in practice I found it quite rare to take place but it surprised me that it did and initially (because of its rarity) I thought there was a bug in my code. But verily a very good observation, answer upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

the F1 score uses a harmonic mean rather than the actual mean, which accounts for the difference

Comment: Hi, this answer doesn’t address the problem because of the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean). The harmonic mean always falls between the minimum and maximum (inclusive).

Comment: You can improve this answer by considering the role of the weights.